# How can i use Azure System Assigned Identity in an App Service that connects to an Azure database?

Tags: azure-managed-identity

I have an App Service in Azure and have created a System Assigned Identity , it gave a Object (principal) Id . I then went to Azure Active Directory and Under Al applications searched for that Identity, it was there.
I then went to the Sql Server and turned on System assigned managed identity under Identity.
I then went to my connection string in the database and set it as

```
Server=my-sql-server.database.windows.net,1433;Database=my-database;Authentication=Active 
 Directory Default
```

But if i start up my App Service and try to login ,  it requires a connection to the database but it doesnt connect , it just gives

```
   <appservice_url>?error=database
```

Any ideas on what is not setup correctly ? or is there a step by step guide on setting this up ?

Comment: what is the underlying exception ?

Answer (score 0):

The part that seems missing is: The managed identity of the app service needs to be granted permissions to access the database

Tutorial is here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-connect-msi-azure-database?tabs=sqldatabase%2Csystemassigned%2Cnetfx%2Cwindowsclient

Comment: Step1 can be done in Azure portal which ive done Step 2 I have done.  I publish ,net code to the app service . I didnt think that I would need to change the way i connect to a db, just the connection string in Azure App configuration ? It still give same error ?

Comment: when you mentioned "The managed identity of the app service needs to be granted permissions to access the database" , i assume that is step 2 part 3. I didnt do parts 1 or 2 of this section  as they are done in Azure portal.  I can login from SSMS . I select "Azure Active Directory -Universal with MFA" , and the user name is NOT the Identity name, its an AD user that already exists, because if i try to connect it will ask for a password and the system identity name doesnt have one.   Just on the side Is there any logging that can possibly catch the error ?

Comment: Step #1 is for managing Azure sql database for local admin and actually has not much to do with how your App accessing the database. Step 2 and 3 are required

Comment: So basically to sum this up I gave a System Identity to my App Service and went to the SQL Server that this App Service uses and gave Access Role to that System Identity as Owner. I then changed the connection string in the App Configuration similar to that above. Your saying thats not enough to work ?    So Do i need to make changes to the way I connect to the db in my .Net code and redeploy ? All that it does is read the setting in App Config and connect wouldnt that be eough ?

Comment: 2 &3 is the proper steps to give MI of app service permissions to access azure sql. "I then went to the Sql Server and turned on System assigned managed identity under Identity"  turned on System assigned managed identity in Azure sql is not needed.

Comment: Sorry I dont get what they mean by these steps.. first it talks about adding a admin user and then it talks about user assigned . Im not using a user assigned. Im using System assigned. I have dones step 2. Now in step 3 it mentions to modify code. So the current .net code that is deployed to azure ; does that need to be changed and re-deployed ? What i mean does the way i connect using .net c# need to be changed ? I was under the impression that setting the connection string in the App Configuration as above would be enough

Comment: I have turned off System assigned managed identity in Azure sql. So now i have it set in the App Service and I have the connectionstring in my app configuration set as above and followed steps 2 & 3 . So it should should successfully connect, but it doesnt . So I guess I would have to debug it from Visual Studio ?